# Unwanted line of text in div

Tags: html, css

So, I got a problem I've been trying to figure out for a while. I'm getting an extra row of text (or so it seems) in my DOM-structure that as far as I can tell is added by the browser. This happens in all browsers I've run the code in (IE8, IE9, Chrome 20, Firefox 11) and I want to remove it.

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="inner">
        <div class="item">
            content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

And this is my CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.item {
    float: left;
    width: 171px;
    position: relative;
    background: #fc0;
}
```

And here is a jsfiddle showing my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/henrikandersson/wMg2m/

As you can see, there is a gap between the top and the yellow item, which as far as I can tell is caused by a line of text above the #inner-div that should not be there.

Comment: There is whitespace just inside `wrapper`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have an invisible control-command `&65279;` following the closing `>` of your wrapper div. Its actually the HTML-encoded [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Just delete that one and you'll be fine.

See [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wMg2m/10/).

Comment: Ah, so that is what that character was... I didn't bother to check! :-)

Answer (score 5):

You have got a special character just after `<div id="wrapper">` that is invisible.

So this works:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="inner">
        <div class="item">
            s
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I retyped the code that you had, this fixed the problem.

The problem could be copy and pasted code, or your text editor.

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org) is the best free Windows text editor.

I found the problem by pasting your code in an ANSI-encoded text file in Notepad++. ANSI cannot display that character, so it changes to a `?`.

Answer (score 1):

add

`#inner {
    float:left;
}`

http://jsfiddle.net/wnhqY/